# How to use a variable in a template in angular 2

Tags: angular, components

I have a component which has chartid as a input which I use like this:

```
<plotlychart chartid="plot"> 
</plotlychart>
```

This is the component. In the template I try to set the id of the div to the variable "chartid", but this is not working.

```
@Component({
selector: 'plotlychart',
template: `
    <div [id]="chartid" 
     style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
    </div>
`,
styleUrls: []
})


export class PlotlyComponent{    
    @Input() chartid: string; 
}
```

**My question** is: Is it possible to use the value of chartid in the template of the component?

**Solution**

```
<plotlychart chartid="plot"> 
</plotlychart>
```

In component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'plotlychart',
template: `
    <div id="{{chartid}}" 
     style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
    </div>
`,
styleUrls: []
})


export class PlotlyComponent{    
    @Input() chartid: string; 
    ngAfterViewInit(){
    Plotly.newPlot(this.chartid, this.data, this.layout, this.options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you are rendering Plotly inside... Maybe the call to Plotly prevents Angular from setting the ID properly?

Comment: You are right. Plotly throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the OP [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023479/how-to-use-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular-2#comment69255151_41023479) he is using Plotly...

Try to wrap the `Plotly.plot(this.chartid, ...)` in a [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview) method. I once had an issue where the component wasn't properly loaded and in the actual page DOM when I called Plotly. Using AfterViewInit ensures the DOM is setup before you call to the charting library.

In your component:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    Plotly.plot(this.chartid, yourdata, ...)
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<plotlychart>` should be like this:

```
<plotlychart [chartid]="plot"> </plotlychart> <!-- (note the [] here!) -->
```

Now in your **PlotlyComponent** template you could just use interpolation for the `chartid`, like so:

```
template: `
    <div id="{{ chartid }}" 
         style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
    </div>
`,
```

Further readings for you:

- [Angular 2 - Template Syntax (inputs & outputs)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs)
- [Angular 2 - Component Communication (parent to child)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)

Comment: I think you should use this without the [ ] around `chartid`.

Comment: Michael W. is right, adding the [] does not work, but the <div id="{{ chartid }}"  does.